# Java floating point literals vs C#

Tags: java, c#, math

I have a quick question that might look strange, but I haven't found the answer around.

I'm converting some Java code for mathematical operations to C# and I hit a case that I don't know how to solve. In fact I found the notation

```
1.e-18
```

Now, I know `1.` is the literal denoting a double precision floating point number in Java, that in C# would be expressed as `1d`, but what the "e" stands for in Java in this case?

Thank you for the support!

**EDIT**

I actually noticed it was `1.e-18` the value I was mentioning

Comment: Is there an integer past the `e`, e.g. `1.e8`?

Comment: That's just a syntax error (http://ideone.com/rBVHiJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work just fine:

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("1.e-18", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
```

`1.e-18` is in scientific notation (or also called exponential notation). It is usually used to represent either very large values or very small values. In English, this notation says "Start with `1.0` and then move the decimal point 18 places to the left", thus giving you a value of `0.000000000000000001`. If it was `1.e+18`, you'd move the decimal point 18 places to the right instead.